# How to Interpret eCognition Best Classification Result

Tags: classification, ecognition, accuracy-assessment

I am learning eCognition using the trial version. Having completed an object-based classification, I wanted to view the accuracy. I can't though find any straight-forward guidance on how to interpret the results of 'best classification result' and 'classification stability'.

My results are as below, if anyone could explain what this means.
[image]